# Ignite Semaphore doesn't support high traffic?

Tags: java, semaphore, ignite

I have a ignite  5 Client + 1 Server cluster, the client receive request from network and send the REQ to ignite server for further processing, in my case, i want to add concurrent limitation for the incoming Request, i use code like this:

```
public boolean handleEntrustRequest(TestEntrustInfo TestEntrustInfo) {

    if(!concurrencySemaphore.tryAcquire()){

        return false;
    }

    try {
        return handleEntrustRequestReal(TestEntrustInfo);
    }finally {

        concurrencySemaphore.release();
    }

}
```

I try to set the limitation number to 100000, i.e. no limitation for incoming request.

In low concurrent traffic, such as around 50~100 the code runs smoothly,
but with higher traffic, I could see Request could not send to Client normally, the request seems hangs and then timeout, but if i remove above code
the incoming Request with 1000 concurrent traffic could be processed quickly.

in this link: 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OPENWHISK/2018-02-14+OW+Tech+Interchange+-+Meeting+Notes
I saw this words:

> New LB, the state is consistent even locally, slots to invokers impl. with semaphores (low level of concurrency);

Also paste the jstack:
please check it here
https://textsave.de/text/E5yRP0iEqSxkzwqw

Comment: It doesn't look like the best use-case for distributed IgniteSemaphore. Every call of `tryAcquire` and `release` can take more than a millisecond mostly because of the network. Why don't you use a plain Semaphore locally on each client node? Do you really need a distributed semaphore?

Comment: Yes, your suggestion is very good, I could add the plain Semaphore locally, it the right solution. Thanks : ) . I just find ignite is so amazing, and forget the local one, but i still curious why the official document have some performance data/description about the ignite semphore, as in my case, it could only suppor a limitaion around 100, very small, and than works like hang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Roman says, using client specific semaphore is enough to solve this issue.